# How volume mounting works in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a very simple node js app and the project structure looks like this.

`index.js`

`package.json`

`package-lock.json`

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:12.18.2-alpine
WORKDIR /test-app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  test-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/test-app
      - "test_app_node_modules:/test-app/node_modules"
volumes:
  test_app_node_modules:
    driver: local
```

If you look at the `volumes` section in `docker-compose.yml` file, first I'm [bind mounting](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) my current directory on the host machine to the `test-app` directory on the container. This means :

1. whatever files or directories that were inside my current dir will get reflected on the container dir and any changes made to the container dir will also get reflected back to the host dir.
2. this means `node_modules` that were installed in the `test-app` dir of the container, during docker build, were overwritten as well.

and the next step in the `volumes` section is [named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). This means:

3. It should copy everything from `test-app/node_modules` inside container to `test_app_node_modules` volume. But the `test-app/node_modules` is empty because step 1 overwrote it.
4. which means we created an empty volume and mounted it to the container.

If this is so, it should be causing missing dependency error but my app is running properly. I'm not sure where I'm getting node_modules from.

Also, I see an empty node_modules folder in the host directory. I assume the reason behind this is `"test_app_node_modules:/test-app/node_modules"` looks for the `node_modules` in the container but it doesn't exist so it creates one and as a result, it gets reflected back to the host dir.

I'm not able to grasp the idea of volume mounting. What is the flow here? How node_modules are begin stored into the volumes when there are none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a purely mechanical level, a couple of things happen here.

Docker sorts the volume mounts.  It knows that `/test-app/node_modules` is a subdirectory of `/test-app`.  So Docker will

1. Create the bind mount from the host directory to the container directory
2. Create an empty `node_modules` directory if required to be a mount point
3. Mount the Docker volume on that mount point

This is where the empty `node_modules` directory on the host comes from: Docker creates it to be a mount point, after it's done the bind mount, so the changes there are reflected in the host content.

When the named volume is mounted in the container, if and only if the named volume is empty, [Docker will copy the content from the *image* into the volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container); this specific step ignores that there's already a volume mounted in the container.  (This also works if the volume is an anonymous volume, which you see in other Node examples; it does not work for host bind mounts, if older content is in the volume, or on Kubernetes.)

So that's why this apparently works.  As the other answers to this question note, this isn't an especially effective use of Docker.  I'd also recommend just deleting these `volumes:`, and directly running `node index.js` on the host if you need a live development setup.

Comment: is it "docker will copy the content from the image into the volume" or "from the container into volume"?

Comment: It's definitely "from the image", even though the linked documentation says "container" everywhere.

Comment: so docker will first look into the container if the data we are trying to mount is there it'll copy from it else it'll look into the image and copy from there?

Comment: If you try to mount an empty named volume, it will copy data from the mount point in the image into the volume.  Then it will mount the volume into the container, hiding whatever was in the container filesystem previously.

Answer (score 0):

in your docker file you have first created `WORKDIR /test-app` inside it you have added a `package.json` file and installed dependencies `RUN npm i` so now there is already `node_module` present inside docker image itself.

after that using `COPY . ./` you are adding extra file like `index` and other all to the docker image.

if you will remove whole `volume` part then also it will work as your docker image contain code and it's dependencies.

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  test-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: but I'm bind mounting the current directory and it'll overwrite everything in the `test-app` dir of the container. No my app is already working.

Comment: i think this will help you out to under stand betterway : https://medium.com/devops-dudes/docker-volumes-and-bind-mounts-2fb4bd9df09d

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you would want to set up a docker container in this way, but the reason it's not working is due to a misunderstanding of the direction in which volumes and bind-mounts work. You say:

> It should copy everything from test-app/node_modules inside container to test_app_node_modules volume. But the test-app/node_modules is empty because step 1 overwrote it.

This is back to front. When you use a volume, the **volume** is copied into the **target**. This is the whole point of volumes - they're designed to allow you to persist data even if you rebuild the container. If you use a bind mounted volume then [the host directory is copied into the target in the docker container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). So your `test_app_node_modules` directory on the host machine is copied into `/test-app/node_modules` in the container. Presumably `test_app_node_modules` contains all your node modules, hence you get no errors about missing modules.

It's only once your container is actually running that the code running in the container can update/delete data in the volume - not when you're building the container.

Comment: My code is working perfectly. It's just I've some confusion about how it's working. yes, the volume is copied into the target but when you start the container for the first time and there is no volume then the data from a container is copied into the volume. That's what I was trying to say.

and `test_app_node_modules` is not a directory but a volume name. and the question was how does this `test_app_node_modules` volume contain all the node_modules?